# SQL GROUP BY a repeating ID throwing - ( not contained in either an aggregate function )

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

Im trying to group my results by the ID here but get the error:
"Column 'Customers.CompanyName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Here is my statement:

```
DECLARE @dateCompare datetime2 = '2011-01-01 00:00:00.0000000';
DECLARE @dateLow datetime2 = '1992-04-01 00:00:00.0000000'; 
DECLARE @dateHigh datetime2 = '1993-06-01 00:00:00.0000000'; 
SELECT o.OrderID, c.CompanyName, o.ShippedDate, DATEDIFF(year, o.OrderDate, @dateCompare) AS 'ElapsedYear'
FROM Orders o , Customers c
WHERE o.ShippedDate >= @dateLow AND o.ShippedDate <= @dateHigh
GROUP BY o.OrderID
```

Whats my fix here? What am I missing?

Comment: What effect are you seeking by using the `GROUP BY` - what would you expect to happen to the various values in the other columns?

Comment: It is very likely that you are missing a condition that shows how `Orders` and `Customers` are related to each other (a join condition).

Answer (score 2):

If you are not trying to summarise the results, you don't need a `group by` clause.

Here, you are grouping by order ID - however, it looks as though you would return one row per order (within the specified date criteria) regardless of whether you included a `group by` clause.

So, remove the `group by` clause.

EDIT: As noted in AndriyM's comment, the query does not currently have a join condition between the two tables - effectively creating a cartesian join (ie. where every record in one table is linked to every record in the other table.) It would definitely be worth adding a join condition to the WHERE clause (or explicitly joining the two tables together).

Comment: My guess is, GROUP BY was an attempt to fix duplicates resulted from the absence of the join condition.

Answer (score 1):

If there are multiple columns apart from the aggregate, you need to include the others as well in the group by clause. Modify it slightly to the following:

```
SELECT o.OrderID, c.CompanyName, o.ShippedDate, DATEDIFF(year, o.OrderDate, @dateCompare) AS 'ElapsedYear'
FROM Orders o , Customers c
WHERE o.ShippedDate >= @dateLow AND o.ShippedDate <= @dateHigh
GROUP BY o.OrderID, c.companyName, o.ShippedDate
```

Comment: The OPs query (and the above) don't contain *any* aggregates (`DATEDIFF` isn't one), so I'm not sure what they're actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can only select columns that are part of your group by clause, and aggregated columns like MAX(colName), AVG(colName) etc